# How to get several lines from a text file?

Tags: c#, string, file, text

I have a text file:

```
hh
    Something sdf....
    one line 
    empty line
    other line
    goal 

    Something apf ee
    one line 
    goal
```

```
List<String> goo = new List<String>();

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("text.txt");
while (file.EndOfStream != true)
{
    string s = file.ReadLine();
    if (s.Contains("Something"))
    {            
        goo.Add(s);
    }
}
```

I want to get all lines after `Something` and until `goal`. 
There are many `Something` and `goal` in the file. I should use array or somthing...?

Comment: More user friendly api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll offer a LINQ-style solution. First, a simple helper extension method for picking subranges out of an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class EnumerableHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetWindows<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, bool> begin,
        Func<T, bool> end)
    {
        List<T> window = null;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (window == null && begin(item))
            {
                window = new List<T>();
            }
            if (window != null)
            {
                window.Add(item);
            }
            if (window != null && end(item))
            {
                yield return window;
                window = null;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can get the windows of text that you're interested in like this:

```
List<List<string>> windows = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    .GetWindows(
        line => line.Contains("Something"),
        line => line.Contains("goal"))
    .ToList();
```

Each item in `windows` is a list of lines of text that correspond to a single "Something...goal" pair.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but should I add reference or something?

Comment: @John I've improved the answer a little bit, being explicit about how you would declare the static class that contains the extension method `GetWindows`. You shouldn't need any references or `using ...` statements outside of the ones that get added for you by default (if you're using a Visual Studio project) - `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, etc.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <string> does not contain a definition for 'GetWindows' and no extension method 'GetWindows'... I'm using Visual Studio Espress 2012.

Comment: @John You need to include that `EnumerableHelper` class in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is meta code

```
Iterate over lines
    if line starts from "Something"
        ShouldAppend = true
    end

    if line starts from "goal"
        ShouldAppend = false
    end

    if ShouldAppend == true

        // append lines to string builder 
        // or add to list as you need

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the state reading.  You have two states from what I can tell.  When you want to add the line and when you don't.  If you keep track of the state then you just check the state when you go to add. A simple, but not the best way as it is not really robust, way of doing this would be something like this:

```
    while (file.EndOfStream != true)
    {   
        bool addStuff = false;
        string s = file.ReadLine();
        if (s.Contains("Something"))
        {   
           addStuff = true;
        }else if (s.Contains("goal")){
           addStuff = false
        }

        if(addStuff){
            goo.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

Warning this is not robust as it won't handle invalid formats and that sort of thing.  This is meant to be a guide to how you can approach this.